# C# make line height adjust to ellipse

Tags: c#, graphics, line, ellipse

There is an ellipse drawn with the following code:

```
graphGraphics = e.Graphics;

graphGraphics.FillEllipse(new SolidBrush(Color.White), this.graphBoundries);
graphGraphics.DrawEllipse(graphPen, this.graphBoundries);
```

I have a line on this graph and it currently just passes right through it. I want to change the lines height to adjust to the ellipse's boundaries as follows so it wont pass through the ellipse:

http://i1379.photobucket.com/albums/ah134/fac7orx2/circlewithlinehelp_zps280d9e76.png

Does anyone know an algorithm to do this? Or maybe even how to just get the ellipse's boundaries and not just the rectangular boundaries?

Comment: consider using the ellipse as a clip region when drawing the line: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.clip%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on my comment, try something like this (untested) code:

```
graphGraphics = e.Graphics;

graphGraphics.FillEllipse(new SolidBrush(Color.White), this.graphBoundries);
graphGraphics.DrawEllipse(graphPen, this.graphBoundries);

GraphicsPath clipPath = new GraphicsPath();
clipPath.AddEllipse(this.graphBoundaries);

graphGraphics.SetClip(clipPath, CombineMode.Replace);

// draw your line
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response. However, I don't seem to have GraphicsPath. I also already have "using System.Drawing;" declared at the top. Any ideas how to add it to my project? Thanks.

Comment: Yup, it's in System.Drawing.Drawing2D.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Ah, thanks. That worked. I thought System.Drawing may have included that, but I had to add System.Drawing.Drawing2D as well. Thanks :). Testing code now will let you know.