# Hide part of line from an arc c#

Tags: c#, line, geometry

I am trying to draw an arc over a line and have it hide part of a line to look like the line is continuous as follows:

http://i188.photobucket.com/albums/z265/fac7orx/hide%20portion%20of%20line1_zpsegcc6vhy.png

So far I am drawing a graph, then a line, then the arc.

```
onPaintGraphics.DrawLine(greenPen, (float)point1.X, 320f, point2.X, 0f); //portion of code drawing the line

graphGraphics.DrawArc(greenPen, 50, 50, 159f, 159f, 90, -180); //portion of code drawing the arc
```

Is my only option to try and fill the arc with a solid color? Should I break up the line from where the arc starts and continue where the arc ends to complete the line? What other options do you think I have to hide that part of the line? Thank you.

Edit:

Modified code thanks to adv12 for solution:

```
public void DrawArcOnLine(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    float arcPosX, arcPosY, arcWidth, archHeight, startAngleArc, arcSweepAngle;

    Graphics graphGraphics = e.Graphics;

    GraphicsPath clipPath = new GraphicsPath();

    Pen greenPen = new Pen(Brushes.MediumSeaGreen);

    arcPosX = 50f;
    arcPosY = 110f;
    arcWidth = 90f;
    archHeight = 90f;
    startAngleArc = 90;
    arcSweepAngle = -180;

    graphGraphics.DrawArc(greenPen, arcPosX, arcPosY, arcWidth, archHeight, startAngleArc, arcSweepAngle);

    clipPath.AddArc(arcPosX, arcPosY, arcWidth, archHeight, startAngleArc, arcSweepAngle);

    graphGraphics.SetClip(clipPath, CombineMode.Exclude);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved using essentially the same code as on your [closely related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27952784/c-sharp-make-line-height-adjust-to-ellipse/27953006#27953006), but with CombineMode.Exclude:

```
GraphicsPath clipPath = new GraphicsPath();
clipPath.AddEllipse(graphBoundaries);

graphics.SetClip(clipPath, CombineMode.Exclude);

// draw your line

graphics.ResetClip(); // remove clip
```

You could simply draw two shorter lines as @Guvante suggests, but this solves the more general problem in case your ellipse isn't centered on the line or you need to mask with a different shape.

Comment: Thanks again! This helped me quite a bit without having to mess around with the line I already am manipulating :).

Answer (score 1):

You should draw two lines. One for the top portion and another for the bottom portion. This should work in every case.

Remember when you tell the graphics system to draw a line you are saying "I want a solid black line between these two points" in your case you don't want that, so split up the area until you can specify something that matches that.

Comment: Cheat is what Guvante is saying. And hes right. You should always cheat where you can in programming, as long as the user doesn't know its 2 different lines, it doesn't matter.